# Make Tess4J get image from PDF file

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, tesseract

How to make Tess4J get image from PDF file?

I'm sarted on the transformation image file to text using OCR (Tess4J). It works fine, I have tested on image and it is great.

```
File imageFile = new File("D:\\HEAD2.png");
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
// Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

try {
    String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (TesseractException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

But I'm facing this problem. I would parse a pdf file that contains image so. I don't kow how to do And I have not found any exemple Tess4J with pdf

I tested this example with Asprise, but I don't find any example like this on Tess4J

```
import com.asprise.util.pdf.PDFReader;
import com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR;

PDFReader reader = new PDFReader(new File("my.pdf"));
reader.open(); // open the file. 
int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

for(int i=0; i < pages; i++) {
   BufferedImage img = reader.getPageAsImage(i);

   // recognizes both characters and barcodes
   String text = new OCR().recognizeAll(image);
   System.out.println("Page " + i + ": " + text); 
}

reader.close(); // finally, close the file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of [pdfutilities.convertpdf2png](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-0.4/net/sourceforge/vietocr/PdfUtilities.html#convertPdf2Png%28java.io.File%29) and use it like you did before with images.

Comment: This code actually wors fine ,But in my directory where is the PDF file images are created .is that necessary

Comment: Maybe it saves images to disk for large PDFs with multiple pages to save some memory. I have currently no idea how to circumvent this. But you could delete those .pdf aftwerwards.

Answer (score 1):

Tess4j has a dependency on *pdfbox*, so you can use this library. It could be something like this:

```
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("YOUR_PDF_FILE_PATH"));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

ITesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();

tesseract.setDatapath("tessdata");
tesseract.setLanguage("spa");

for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);

    try {
        String str = tesseract.doOCR(bufferedImage);
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (TesseractException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OCR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
document.close();
```

I'm using here Tessj4 4.5 and pdf-box 2.0.
You can also check
https://colwil.com/how-to-extract-text-from-a-scanned-pdf-using-ocr-in-java/.